# If $a^2+b^2+c^2=D$ and a and b are consecutive positive integers and $ ab = c $ then prove that $ D^{1/2} $ is an odd integer

Tags: number-theory, factoring

Here is my approach:
since a and b are consecutive integers there are two possibilities
$a = b+1$
and $a = b-1$
substituting this into the first equation we get 
$ 2 b^2 + 2 b + c^2 + 1 = D $ after this I do not know what to do.
help in any form would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't used the fact that $c=ab$.

Comment: The two cases $a = b+1$ and $a = b-1$ are basically the same. One of $a$ and $b$ is $1$ larger than the other, and one of $a$ and $b$ happens to have the name $a$. You may safely assume the two properties coincide in the same variable. We call this "assuming without loss of generality".

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, let $a = b+1$. Then $$a^2+b^2+c^2 = (b+1)^2+b^2+b^2(b+1)^2 = (b^2+b+1)^2$$ Now, consider that whether $b$ is even or odd, $b^2+b$ will be even (as it is either an even number plus an even number, or an odd number plus an odd number), so $b^2+b+1$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can do it:
you have already done a portion of it and got $ 2 b^2 + 2 b + c^2 + 1 = D $
now use $ab=c$
and substitute $a=b-1$ or $a=b+1$ (they both lead to the same thing)
to get $b(b+1)=c$ or $b(b-1)=c$
plug this value of c to get
$c+c^2+1=D$,
$(c+1)^2=D$,
so $D^{1/2} = c+1$
and since the product of consecutive integers ($a$ and $b$) is always even 
it means $c$ is even so $c+1$ is odd

Comment: sorry for not formatting this using mathjax as i am using my friends laptop